# Android Source Code Gmail Attachment download Detected as virus

Tags: gmail, android-source

I have send a Android Source Code few months back that time it did not restrict the file to upload. Now when I am trying to download it form sent box it is restricting me. How can I get that file any idea.

Answer (score 0):

I got my own ans after a long search that to this blog. Check out the link

http://lutfi.belwael.com/2015/01/how-to-retrieve-blocked-gmail-attachments/